# Calculus 2: Volume of a Solid of Revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

> From Rogawski ET 2e section 6.3, exercise 22.
>
> Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the curves $x=\sqrt{8\sin y}, x=0$ about the $y$-axis over the interval $1.05\le y\le1.57$
>
> Volume = $\boxed{50.2654}$

I have been stumped on this question for almost two hours now, and I have tried changing the axises from x to y and I then attempted to integrate for dy. However, the answer I have entered and have been repeatedly getting was $16\pi$ or $50.2654$, and sadly this is not the right answer. If anyone could offer any help I would be tremendously grateful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  Usually the first question you will see of this type is to find the volume obtained when the area below a certain curve is rotated about the **x-axis**.  In this case the formula is
$$V=\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \pi y^2\,dx\ .$$
Can you see what you need to change to attack the problem you have been asked?

Comment: Yes that is the formula I used which takes the square root away from the equation and leaves me with 8pi times the integration of sin(y), which in turn becomes -cos(y) when integrated, then I substituted the boundaries in for (8pi)(-cos(1.57))-((8pi)(-cos(1.05)))

Comment: Well that's the correct answer as far as I can see, but it doesn't work out to $16\pi$ or $50.2654$.

Comment: You are right indeed. Thank you very much for your help that is the right answer. I incorrectly input the information into the website. Thank you for your response it was very helpful.